# Can I dispatch request action in both constructor and ngOnInit?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, reducers, ngrx-effects

I have a scenario where I need to dispatch request action from both constructor and ngOnInit and load the data in both functions. I tried but on the second call either of the dispatch is not invoking and data I see is the same data which I got from the previous call. I want to know how to I achieve it

I have tried calling dispatch from another class where my condition satisfies.

```
constructor(
  private store: Store<AppState>,
  private globalLoginService: GlobalLoginService,
) {
  this.filterService.dashboardModified.subscribe(val => {
    if (this.filterService.IsdashboardModified === "true") {
      this.getProfileDatafromStore();
    }
  });
}

public getProfileDatafromStore() {
  this.store.dispatch(
    new GetUserProfilesRequested(userEmail)
  );
  this.userProfiles$ = this.store.select(getUserProfile);
  this.userProfiles$
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
    .subscribe(storeval => {
      if (storeval) {
        this.userProfileData = storeval
        this.loginProfile(this.userProfileData);
      }
    });
}

public ngOnInit() {
  this.getProfileDatafromStore();
}
```

I want the data to be loaded each time when a call happens from ngOnIt and constructor

Comment: What is the motivation here?

Comment: What does your effect looks like because if you are using a switchMap to make the call, the first call could be cancelled before resolving, when the second call is made. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap. Why would you need both dispatch?

Comment: Tried using mergeMap and concatMap no different output. The second call is dispatched with different user, so the data what I get in second call is different to the first user.

Comment: so, I am getting data of different users, when I logged in with `sample1` user I see the user data and navigated to another screen. In this screen I have an option of shadowing a user of `sample2` which gives different output. This both happens in dispatching in ngOnInt and Constructor tried working on limiting but I get different screen outputs

Answer (score 0):

Instead of resubscribing on every `getProfileDataFromStore` function call, you can create the subscription once and simply dispatch actions.

```
constructor(
  private store: Store < AppState >,
  private globalLoginService: GlobalLoginService,
) {

  this.setUpgetProfileDatafromStore(); // <-- setup observables before anything happens

  this.filterService.dashboardModified.subscribe(val => {
    if (this.filterService.IsdashboardModified === "true") {
       this.getProfileDatafromStore(); 
    }
  });


}

public setUpgetProfileDatafromStore(){

  this.userProfiles$ = this.store.select(getUserProfile);
  this.userProfiles$
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
    .subscribe(storeval => {
      if (storeval) {
        this.userProfileData = storeval
        this.loginProfile(this.userProfileData);
      }
    });

}

public getProfileDatafromStore() {
  this.store.dispatch(
    new GetUserProfilesRequested(userEmail)
  );
}

public ngOnInit() {
  this.getProfileDatafromStore();

}
```